# Why doesn't Python see a specified int() attribute?

Tags: python

I am building a Python-based, single-player, word-based, MMORPG game. I am a beginner and wish this to be a simple task. I have coded the moving part, in which the character moves from one site to another. It seems to not work, as Python seems to not be able to see my attributes. This is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Maelstrom/Maelstrom Move.py", line 51, in 
>       place = test.place
>   AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'place'

This is my code:

```
class Player(object):
    """The player."""
    def __init__(self,name="name",inv=[],equip=[],stats=[],place=int("001"),knownplaces={}):
        self.name = input("What name do you want?")
        knownplaces[int("001")]="Ruby City"
        knownplaces[int("002")]="Ruby Inn"
        knownplaces[int("003")]="Ruby Forests"
        knownplaces[int("004")]="Ruby Countryside"
        knownplaces[int("005")]="Witch Hideout"
    def __str__():
        rep = self.movepossible
    def movepossible(self,position):
        #001--Ruby City
        #002--Ruby Inn
        #003--Ruby Forests
        #004--Ruby Countryside
        #005--Witch Hideout
        if position==int("001"):
            possible=[int("002"),int("003")]
            return possible
        elif position==int("002"):
            possible=[int("001")]
            return possible
        elif position==int("003"):
            possible=[int("001"),int("004")]
            return possible
        elif position==int("004"):
            possible=[int("001"),int("003"),int("005")]
            return possible
        elif position==int("005"):
            possible=[int("004")]
            return possible
        else:
            return null
    def move(self,position):
        possiblewords=[]
        print('Choose between paths:'/n)
        possible = movepossible(self, position)
        for m in range(0,len(possible),1):
            possiblewords.append(knownplaces[possible[m]])
        for n in range(0,len(possiblewords),1):
            print(m+':'+possiblewords[m-1] /n)
        choice=input('Make your choice...')
        if choice-1 <= len(possiblewords):
            self.place=possible[choice-1]

    def showposition(self):
        print(knownplaces[self.place])
test = Player()
while True:
    place = test.place
    test.move(place)
    test.showposition()
```

Comment: `Player()` has no attribute `place`.

Comment: Careful with [mutable default arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments). Anyway, your problem is that you are never defining any instance variables, only using local variables, and those won't be defined in other functions/methods

Comment: This is somewhat beside the point, but isn't a "single-player MMORPG" a contradiction in terms (MMORPG = Massively *multiplayer* online...)?

Comment: I'm making something similar to a MMORPG in the system, but it is now single-player because I'm not expert in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time the line `place = test.place` is executed, the `place` attribute on your `Player` instance has not been defined.

The first time the `place` attribute gets set is in the `move()` method. i.e. Attempting to access `place` before calling `move()` will result in the error you are observing.

You should assign a default value to `self.place` in the initializer for the `Player` class.